# Command line join attributes by location using OGR

Tags: vector, ogr, fields-attributes, select-by-location, attribute-joins

I have two overlapping vector files (polygons and sample) and want to do a spatial join from the command line to extract all features in polygons that intersect with sample. Essentially I want to have the same result as if I was using the "Join attributes by location" function in QGIS with "Only keep matching records" including the attribute table.

This should be possible with OGR and a SQL query, but I can't get the syntax to work.
So far I have tried with a vrt file following this [description](http://www.spatialthoughts.com/blog/gis/ogr-spatial-join/)

And then something like:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE ST_INTERSECTS (polygons,sample)" -dialect SQLITE plogonesandsample.vrt
```

However I find this very cumbersome and not generic.

I seek a solution that works from the command line.